# Firebase security rules resource.data not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The goal is essentially to compare an element of something, such as a Last in Messaging, and just to check it isn't null or equal to another value.

```
match /Messaging/ {userId} {
   allow read: if resource.data.Last != null;
}
```

`resource.data` is not null, but getting any field from the firestore database (`Last` in this case) is null.

[image: Screenshot of collection if needed...]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your collection? Also note that there is a space in `/Messaging/ {userId}`.

Comment: Done. Would the space actually cause the issue. That line works in other places in our security code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the goal if this check. What is `resource.data.Message != null` supposed to assert? The document you show doesn't have a `Message` field, so how is that document supposed to behave against these rules - and what does it actually do? --- In addition: please edit your question to show the minimal code that doesn't work against these rules.

Comment: That was just an example. We are actually trying to check if User1 or User2 is equal to the current user so that only the two members of the chat can read or write it.